# how to remove dependencies of webmin post apt-get --purge remove

Tags: package-management, apt, uninstall

I removed webmin, as I no longer needed it.

But I removed it with `apt-get --purge remove`,
thinking it would remove dependencies and simply retrace back what it did during installation. It turns out I was wrong, and aptitude or --auto-remove had to be used.

I would like to keep my machine clean of unneeded scripts and installs.

how do I remove stuff probably has been left behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apt-get autoremove --purge`.

It removes any unnecessary leftover packages and with the `--purge` option, the configuration files are also removed.

Comment: thank you, I didn't realize that even though package webmin doesn't exist on my comp, apt-get can still read dependencies list and do as requested!

I love linux.